# How to seach for multiple data in a single row mysql laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

i want to check 3 columns in the same row for values. My columns are

```
|column1|  column2 |column3 |
|-------|----------|--------|
| row1  |   row2   |  row3  |
```

I want to check if row1 has value, if it doesn't then i want to insert into it, same as row2 if it doesn't have value i want to insert into it and same as row 3. The goal is that when a user registers we give 3 gifts to them. so when you register row1, row2 and row3 are null, i want to insert into them according to ASCENDING ORDER in the database.

For example: if row1 is empty then it should update it from being empty to a toy or a baloon and then for the two other rows, but if the second row has a value then it should go for the third row, if the third has a value then it should go to the next line

Comment: I would definitely rethink this database design. I think separating gifts into a separate table with many-to-many relationship will do you much better in future. Or one-to-many (user has gifts) if all gifts are unique. And then count the number of gifts a user has before inserting a new one.

Comment: Those "rows" are not rows, those are columns. Rows go from top to bottom, columns from left to right. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little but confusing between rows and columns the way you use them.

So first case, following the table you provided and your title. You want to update a single row that has 3 columns. Assuming said rows also has a primary key like `id`, you can

```
$gift = Gift::find($id);
$gift->column1 = $row->column1 ? $row->column1 : $toy; //if empty, add toy
$gift->column2 = $row->column2 ? $row->column2 : $baloon; //if empty, add baloon
$gift->save();
```

Second case, you actually define this properly and make each gift in a different row, and create a one to many relationship between Gift and User. In User model:

```
public function gifts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Gift::class, 'user_id');
}
```

When the user register, he has not gift yet. You actually at the gift one by one without all the hasle.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->gifts()->saveMany([
    new Gift(['type' => 'toy', ...]); //fill all the attributes
    new Gift(['type' => 'toy', ...]); //fill all the attributes
    new Gift(['type' => 'toy', ...]); //fill all the attributes
]);
```

And voila!

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what i wanted